# DevOps Server resource version picker ignores selection and uses latest

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-server-2022

I have a deployment pipeline that uses a build pipeline as a resource. I want to be able to select the build version to use when I manually run the deployment but the run ignores any version I select in the resource version picker and simply uses the latest. What am I missing?

I select the [previous build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5FnP.png) which has an id of 8517.
But in the logs it shows it is downloading the current build with id [8528](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CQGe.png).

This is the deployment pipeline:

```
trigger:
 - none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Console
    source: Build.Console

extends:
  template: Deploy.yml
  parameters:
    ...
```

The template it uses is pretty simple:

```
parameters:
  ...

jobs:
- deployment: Console
  workspace:
    clean: outputs
  environment: 'Test'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - download: Console
        ...
```

[The documentation seems to imply this is straight forward.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=schema#manual-version-picker-for-resources-in-the-create-run-dialogue)

In researching this I've only found discussions on the picker being [available](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7635) as of 2020 and using it like I have above. I haven't found any discussion on it not working other than [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826090/how-to-download-artifacts-specified-in-run-pipeline-dialog?rq=1), but his solution is what I'm already doing.

Originally I was thinking the issue was related to the use of triggers in the resource definition because the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines) mentions that triggers will always use the triggering resource ("used only for manual or scheduled triggers."), but even simplifying it down to only the source pipeline as above doesn't let the run use the selected version.

The only got'cha I can think of is I'm using the `download` step instead of a task. The template is used by a triggered release pipeline for another environment and that works well, so I'm reluctant to modify it to use the [`DownloadPipelineArtifact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task with the `buildType: specific` settings.

---

### Update 1:

I've tried cleaning the entire workspace as [Miao Tian-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16162444/miao-tian-msft) suggested with not luck.

---

### Update 2:

I've looked at specifying the version explicitly using a variable but there are two issue with it. First, [it doesn't appear to be an option to use a variable in the resource declaration.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-variables-at-resourcesrepositoriesrepository/816606) Second, the version id [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines) are determined by the `resources:` section and so wouldn't be available to use for a `version:` property inside that section.

Comment: Hi, I noticed in your screenshot, it shows the log:  `Downloading artifacts for build:8528`. I checked my log and I found it is `Download from the specified build: #51` and task name is Download build artifacts. Can you share more details of your task name?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the deployment pipeline and template you shared, I found it works in my pipeline when I use `workspace:   clean: all` in the Template Deploy.yml.

It is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace):

> When you specify one of the clean options, they're interpreted as follows:
>
> - `outputs`: Delete `Build.BinariesDirectory` before running a new job.
> - `resources`: Delete `Build.SourcesDirectory` before running a new job.
> - `all`: Delete the entire `Pipeline.Workspace` directory before running a new job.

When you download the pipeline resources with `download: Console`, it will download artifact to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)\Console`. So, we need to clean all to clean the `Pipeline.Workspace` directory.

My sample:

Deployment pipeline:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Console
    source: one
extends:
  template: Deploy.yml
```

Template Deploy.yml：

```
jobs:
- deployment: Console
  environment: 'myEnvironment'
  workspace:
    clean: all
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - download: Console
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\Console'
            ArtifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'Container'
```